# A question in matrix norm.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality

Let $A \in {M_n}$ and $\left\| {\left| . \right|} \right\|$ be a matrix norm on ${M_n}$.Why does ${\left\| {\left| A \right|} \right\|_2} \le \left\| {\left| A \right|} \right\|_1^{\frac{1}{2}}\left\| {\left| A \right|} \right\|_\infty ^{\frac{1}{2}}$?

Comment: See also "Hölder inequality".

Comment: Dear @Kavir I see that, although you have already asked 5 question in this site and received answers in most of them, you have not mark a best answer in any of them. You can do it so by clicking on the checkmark next to the answer that you think is the one that helped you the most. Please [read here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) for more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Let $r(A)=max\{|\lambda|:\lambda\ is\ eigenvalue\ of\ A\}$.
 Then $||A||_2=\sqrt{r(A^TA)}$

Now, for any matrix norm $||\cdot||$ we have $r(A)\leq||A||$.

Thus $||A||_2=\sqrt{r(A^TA)}\leq\sqrt{||A^TA||_\infty}\leq\sqrt{||A^T||_\infty||A||_\infty}=\sqrt{||A||_1||A||_\infty}$

Comment: You can bound $r(A^TA)$ directly by $\|A^TA\|_\infty$. For any matrix norm $\|\cdot\|$, which is consistent with some vector norm, $r(X)\leq\|X\|$.

Comment: Yes, thank you!